# "as well" or "as well as" in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it "as well" or "as well as" in the following sentence. If it is the latter, doesn't we need one more "as" after it?

> Those who impose this condition differ **as to** what sort or degree
>   of access is required, **as well as to** just what it is to which one
>   must have access of the proper sort.

Comment: This sentence reads like pompous guff written by someone who does not know what they are talking about, but intends to impress.

Answer (score 0):

> Those who impose this condition differ [as to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as#as-as-a-preposition) what sort or degree of access is required, [as well (as)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-well-as) to just what it is to which one must have access of the proper sort.

The word "as" can be used in different ways, as a conjunction, a preposition, an adverb or a pronoun.

In the above sentence, both uses are a preposition.  In the first case "as to" is being used as a preposition to the noun "degree".  In the second case, "as well as" is being used as a multi word preposition to... well something.  The author really is mincing the words! I would suspect the noun "access".  "as well as" means "in addition to".

> doesn't we need one more "as" after it?

In answer to the question "do we need one more 'as'" or "don't we need one more 'as'", I would say no. It's an unnecessarily complicated sentence but breaks down roughly as follows, no additional "as" (prepositions) required.

[to just] = preposition, adjective

[what it is] = noun that the adjective refers to

[to which] = preposition, pronoun, refers to antecedent

Answer (score 0):

> Those who impose this condition differ **as to** what sort or degree of access is required, **as well as to** just what it is to which one must have access of the proper sort.
>
> Those who X differ **as to** what sort or degree of access is required, ...

The group of people who favor X have different opinions on what access is required. Somne say more, some say less, some say one kind of access, some say a different kind.

> ... **as well as to** just what it is to which one must have access

These same people who favor X also have different opinions on what people must be grante4d access **to**. Some say it must be access to Y, others say access to Z.

Yes the original sentence is complex, but see what a lot of meaning  it packs in.  Two different disputes on related topics among sub-groups of a single group. I wopuld leave out the "to" in "**as well as to** " but I can't say that it is wrong to leave it in.

I would say, by the way, that the first "as to" serves as the object of the verb differ. It shows, or introduces the clause that shows, what they differ about. "as well as to" implies a re-sue of the verb differ with the same subject but a different object, because there is a second difference of opinion among the same group of people.